# Checkbox missing

Tags: android, checkbox, tablelayout, tablerow

Hi guys i have problem creating my layout, previously i use this layout and it is working but today when i reopen my xml, my check box is missing, anyone have any idea that can help me solve the problem ??

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E7FEFF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFFFF0"
            android:text="Opp SAFRA Tampines"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:width="1000dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" >

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  5"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text02"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Pasir Ris Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="100dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:25   15:36    15:47"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  8"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Tampines Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:26   15:27    15:36"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  15"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Tampines Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:23   15:28    15:30"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  18"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Tampines Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:30   15:31    15:34"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  21"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Pasir Ris Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:23   15:26    15:39"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  23"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Tampines Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:29   15:30    15:39"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  59"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Changi Village Ter"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:20   15:31    15:45"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  65"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Tampines Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:21   15:31    15:40"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  67"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Tampines Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:23   15:25    15:29"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  168"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Woodland Reg Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:30   15:39    15:59"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:text="  518"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  Pasir Ris Int"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="850px" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:checked="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  15:21   15:39    15:55"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="650dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/next" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: i know you got answer.Small info don't use `PX` use `DP` for width and Height, for `textSize` use `sp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below property from each CheckBox :

```
android:layout_weight
```

Add below properties to each TextView which is placed with CheckBox in Row :

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

**Example :**

```
<TableRow>

   <TextView
      android:background="#E7FEFF"
      android:text="  Tampines Int"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textSize="15dp"
      android:width="850px" />

    <CheckBox
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:checked="false" />
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: what i actually need is inserting coordinate and allow user to click on

Comment: @GlynnNeo Refer this [Link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html) for Google Map V2